# Why is access denied for sudo user to run an update.php in mediawiki maintenance?

Tags: database, shell, phpmyadmin, command, mediawiki

I'm a mediawiki admin, I have all the rights granted on the Database, I am a registered sudo user and when I try to run an update command it says: Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBConnectionError from line 1460 of /home/user/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/loadbalancer/LoadBalancer.php: Cannot access the database: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (localhost).

I have tried to sudo this command. I am a registered sudo user, I give my password correctly and then the same error pulls up like "access denied for user". I have installed a Patroller extension, I have edited the LocalSettings etc, the last thing I must do according to the guide is to run a php update.php. Since I am unable to do so, I always end up with this error message inside my mediawiki page when I click on "patrol edits": Fatal exception of type "Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBQueryError". So, my sql table hasn't been updated with the patrol extension because I cannot run the update command from my PuTTy.

Comment: You have to ensure that your user is actually also a DBMS registred user; What DBMS did you install?

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag since this is not related to the SQL _language_, Instead you should add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: sorry, I use phpMyAdmin for my databases. My user "user@localhost" that gets denied, is registered in my DBMS and has all privileges granted.

Comment: You usually don't want to use `sudo` for `update.php`, `git ...`, etc.

Comment: I tried with and without sudo anyway and i get the same message about access denied for the user